# Excel Macro: check whether the current cell has a substring as another cell

Tags: excel, macros

Without using VBA (I can do it in VBA, but just want to try whether a macro can do it as well, but I haven't figured it out yet),

I have two sheets. Sheet A includes a column of names such as its cell like:

> Wright

Sheet B includes a column of names well, but with more letters like title in one cell such as:

> Mr. Wright

Sheet A to B is in a relationship of one-to-many (Wright in Sheet A might have multiple rows with Mr.Wright in Sheet B).

If in Sheet B, how to write a macro with some function to achieve: to check whether 'Mr.Wright' has a substring in a cell in Sheet A.

(I think about it might be easier to start from Sheet A: might with regex, find all matches in Sheet B with INDEX or MATCH first. It's much better if it can be done from Sheet B in one shot)

Comment: Sorry for the question. Don't bother. I think the most proper way is to use VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a macro called sub_in_name.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sub_in_name()

Dim x, i As Long

Dim endofcells1, endofcellsmany As Long

endofcells1 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
endofcellsmany = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B"))

For x = 1 To endofcells1
    For i = 1 To endofcellsmany


If (InStr(1, Cells(i, 2), Cells(x, 1), vbTextCompare)) Then
Cells(i, 2 + x).Value = "True"
Else
Cells(i, 2 + x).Value = "False"
End If

    Next i
Next x


End Sub
```

`Intr(start, SearchStr, SearchInStr, vbaoption)` is the main function to make this work. `Cells(i, 2 + x)` is indexed based off the number of non-empty cells in column "A"

Make sure to clear the cells content for each trial; after column "B".

For example put in Column "A" & Column "B" and you will get columns "C:D"

```
 Column "A"       Column "B"        Column "C"    Column "D"

 Wright           Mr. Wright        True          False

 Roger            Wright Jr.        True          False

                  Wright the Ivth.  True          False

                  Sally             False         False
```

Answer (score 0):

Roughly similar logic. Originally I wanted to use existing macro functions to do it. Finally it ended up like making a customized function like below:

Inspired by another thread in stack overflow. I made a code to do full checking like user3553260's. But I think a function is not a bad choice as well, considering if the efficiency is not the top one concern here.

```
Function LookupName(lookupValue As Variant, lookupRange As Range) As String

Dim r As Long   
Dim c As Long   

Dim s As String 

s = "No"

For r = 1 To lookupRange.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To lookupRange.Columns.Count

        If Not IsEmpty(lookupRange.Cells(r, c).Value) Then

          If InStr(LCase(lookupValue), LCase(lookupRange.Cells(r, c).Value)) Then

            s = "Yes"
            Exit For

          End If

        End If

    Next
Next

LookupName = s

End Function
```